# Odd behaviour of radio buttons in WinForms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, .net-3.5

I have some very plain radio buttons in a very plain group box in a very plain WinForms form, in a very plain VB.NET project. This is as simple as possible.

[image]

The odd behaviour is that if one is selected, and I click another, the selected radio box unchecks, and *that's it*. A *second* click is required to select the clicked radio button.

Designer code for one of the radio buttons:

```
Me.rbPhaseM00.AutoSize = True
Me.rbPhaseM00.CausesValidation = False
Me.rbPhaseM00.Checked = Global.CnstrSirfNetIntrc.My.MySettings.Default.rbPhaseM00
Me.rbPhaseM00.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Checked", Global.CnstrSirfNetIntrc.My.MySettings.Default, "rbPhaseM00", True, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
Me.rbPhaseM00.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 19)
Me.rbPhaseM00.Name = "rbPhaseM00"
Me.rbPhaseM00.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(46, 17)
Me.rbPhaseM00.TabIndex = 21
Me.rbPhaseM00.Text = "M00"
Me.rbPhaseM00.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
```

What property is causing this? There are no events attached to the radio buttons, no other controls in the group box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two.  First is the Parent, they all have to have the same one.  Double-check that with View + (Other Windows) + Document Outline, verify that the radio button controls are all nested inside the group box and not just overlapping it.  Drag + drop to fix.

And they all have to have the AutoCheck property set to True.

After edit: the data binding looks like a hazard.  Unbind to test.  There are several existing SO questions that talk about it, find them by googling "Winforms databinding radiobuttons".

Comment: It's the data binding. Will research some more. Thanks!